# Removing the navigation Cube from the UI

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I can't seem to find a way to hide the standard navigation Cube for the Forge Viewer.

I only want to display only the `homeViewWrapper`, but I want to hide both `infoButton` (successfully did) and the `viewcube` (unsuccessfully). If I remove the `viewcube`, all the UI related to the cube gets removed (including the HomeWrapper which I want to show.

Comment: please remove the css tag from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the view cube from the viewport only, you can use `Viewer3D.displayViewCube( false )` to do this. Don't use `Viewer3D.displayViewCubeUI( false )`, it will hide view cube, home button, and info. button together.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/